# Trying to create a custom initializer method

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization

So I know there a bunch of questions like this but none of their solutions seems to be helping me.

Let me start of by saying I am using storyboards so I would use `initWithCoder` instead of `initWithNibName:`.

Now that we got that bit out of the way.  So, simply I want to pass an object to another view with a custom initializer.

So in my second view I would have code like this:

```
- (id) initWithMyLifeChangingObject: (MagicType *)object {

     //Apparently this is important
     self = [super init];

     //Do some stuff with my magical object

     //You know the story
     return self;

}
```

And as the story goes you need to call your world class init:

`[SecondClass alloc] initWithMyLifeChangingObject:object];`

But `initWithMyLifeChangingObject:` isn't recognized and gives me a build error saying it is not in existence... so what do I do.

Comment: Did you add the method signature to the .h file of SecondClass?

Comment: Ya know... I did not... thanks @rdelmar